# Assign to list of interfaces in Go

Tags: go

I have an interface `Foo` with a struct `foo` that implements it. I have an API that accepts a list of `Foo`s, and I need to pass in my list of `foo`s, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type foo struct {
}

func (f foo) Do() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
}

type Foo interface {
    Do()
}

func main() {
    var f foo
    var F Foo
    F = f // compiles just fine
    var fs []foo
    var Fs []Foo
    Fs = fs // doesn't compile for some reason
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious as I'm very new to Go, but why doesn't this compile?

Comment: This is covered in the official FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: I saw that, but was unsure if it only applied to `interface{}` slices, or any slice declared with an interface type.

Comment: interface{} is a totally normal type and follows the same rules like e.g. chan[]int. (Only struct{} has an additional rule.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slice of interfaces is not an interface - the layout of an interface and the layout of a concrete structure are different. Therefore, you can't assign `[]foo` to `[]Foo`.

This is a common enough error that it's even documented on the golang wiki: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

If you *need* a slice of `Foo` interfaces then you'll have to just make one and assign them in a loop. Example taken from the wiki:

```
var dataSlice []int = foo()
var interfaceSlice []interface{} = make([]interface{}, len(dataSlice))
for i, d := range dataSlice {
    interfaceSlice[i] = d
}
```

Comment: I saw that, but was hoping it only applied to `interface{}`, not any given interface. Ah, what a pain. Thanks for the help!